# C++ program to find number of increasing peaks

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

***problem---***
a peak is defined as in a sequence A=a1,a2,..ai-1,ai,ai+1..an, if ai-1 < ai > ai+1 i.e it is a local maxima , find the number of increasing peaks where an increasing peak is a peak which is greater than all previous peaks.

***My approach ---***
Find all local peaks in the array and push them to a vector.
Find the number of increasing peaks by iterating through that vector.

***Issue--***
Code shows bad_alloc() error while running

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
    int n, i,t, count,x;
    cout << "Enter No of Elements";
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n;i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    vector<int> max;
    max.reserve(n);
    if (arr[1]<arr[0]){
        t = arr[0];
        max.push_back(t);
        count = 1;
    }
    for (i = 1; i+1<n;i=i++){
        if(arr[i]>arr[i-1]&&arr[i]>arr[i+1])
            t = arr[i];
            max.push_back(t);

    }
    if(arr[n-1]>arr[n-2]){
        t = arr[n - 1];
        max.push_back(t);
    }
    for (i = 1; i < max.size();i++)
    {
        if (max[i]>max[i-1])
            count++;
    }
    cout << count;
    cin >> x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int arr[n];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a compile-time constant, not a runtime variable.  You're already using `std::vector`, so use it here:  `std::vector<int> arr(n);`

Comment: Why do you need to store peaks? Can't you just remember the last maximum peak and a count? You probably don't need to store arr either, just process the numbers as you read them in.

Comment: *Code shows bad_alloc() error while running* -- Where is the test data?

Comment: And which line gives you the bad_alloc error? The vector declaration or a push_back?

Comment: The `i=i++` in `for (i = 1; i+1<n;i=i++)` is a significant ugly. There's no way to be sure of the outcome. You may have an infinite loop here.

Comment: You also have some misleading indentation inside that loop. The `if` only covers `t = arr[i];`. `max.push_back(t);` runs every time.

Comment: I'm going to toss this into a compiler set to anally retentive and see what warnings pop out: https://godbolt.org/z/hrqsvrqejNothing significant that hasn't already been brought up.

Comment: Clang finds the same and the code can't compile under visual studio, so I didn't check it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, see [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H).

Secondly, arrays MUST have a constant value. They cannot get their value from any sort of input, etc.

Thirdly, you have an infinite loop:

```
for (i = 1; i+1<n;i=i++){
        if(arr[i]>arr[i-1]&&arr[i]>arr[i+1])
            t = arr[i];
            max.push_back(t);

    }
```

When we enter the `for` loop, we begin with `i` at 1 and (for the example, `n` will be 3) `n` with 3. We see all go well, and when we compare 1+1 is smaller than two, so we continue. Next, we post increment `i` to 2 but, as the post increment returns the value of   `i` before the increment, we reset `i` to 1! (This is actually undefined behavior, but in your case you got this infinite loop.) Uh oh, that wasn't what we meant, so we fix this code to this:

```
for (i = 1; i + 1 < n; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > arr[i - 1] && arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
        t = arr[i];
    max.push_back(t);

}
```

The increment/decrement already modify int's value, which is why we don't need to assign it. Finally, we have to fix this error:

```
if (arr[1] < arr[0]) {
    t = arr[0];
    max.push_back(t);
    count = 1;
}
```

This is a bit tricky, but the user might enter an number like 0, which would cause this to malfunction, while tricking the `new` operator. To fix this, we can prevent this by replacing:

```
cin>>n;
```

With:

```
while (cin >> n && n < 1);
```

Which will read into n while n is less than 1;

Also, the reason I used `new` is because it is what you use for dynamic allocation, or variable sized arrays. This allocates it:

```
int* arr = new int[n];
```

and this deallocates it:

```
delete[] arr;
```

For more info, read on pointers. Final Result:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, i, t, count, x;
    count = 0;
    cout << "Enter No of Elements";
    while (cin >> n && n < 1);
    int* arr = new int[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    vector<int> max;
    max.reserve(n);
    if (arr[1] < arr[0]) {
        t = arr[0];
        max.push_back(t);
        count = 1;
    }
    for (i = 1; i + 1 < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > arr[i - 1] && arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
            t = arr[i];
        max.push_back(t);

    }
    if (arr[n - 1] > arr[n - 2]) {
        t = arr[n - 1];
        max.push_back(t);
    }
    for (i = 1; i < max.size(); i++)
    {
        if (max[i] > max[i - 1])
            count++;
    }
    cout << count;
    cin >> x;
    return 0;
}
```

Also, I initialized `count`, because it was only being initialized in the `if`.

**Note:** Quoting @user4581301

> note on the use of new here. Prefer  `std::vector` when you need a dynamic array. std::vector automates the allocation and deallocation with RAII so you can be sure you have no leaks.

Comment: A note on `i=i++`: The behaviour is undefined. In this case it appears the asker got an infinite loop, but you can't count on always getting an infinite loop.

Comment: @user4581301 thank you, I forgot about that

Comment: A note on the use of `new` here. Prefer ` std::vector` when you need a dynamic array. `std::vector` automates the allocation and deallocation with [RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii) so you can be sure you have no leaks.

Comment: @user4581301 That is true, but to keep it as similar to the original code, I will keep it like this. If you like, I will add a note advising on this.

Comment: Worth an edit to point out the `max.push_back(t);` in the loop of doom always runs.

Comment: And at this point you might be able to see why I didn't answer this question myself:  To cover all of the little mistakes the answer goes on for pages. [mre]s rock.